# OCI8 doesn't enable on windows 8 + php 5.2.5

Tags: php, oracle10g, oci8

Previously I connected Oci 8 on the same machine without using instantclient. I just installed xampp-win32-1.6.6a and  edited the `apache/php.ini`. (Not sure) After installing VS2013, my `php_info()` doesn't show oci8 enabled.

If possible, I want to connect without 'instantclient'. I have already uninstalled VS 2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way without instantclient. Just copied files from *instantclient 10.2* and paste them into,

> C:/XAMP/APACHE/BIN
>
> C:/XAMP/PHP/EXT

Restarted Apache and it is awesome.